# jQuery - resetting a countdown timer

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a countdown timer that resets every time a `<button>` is pressed. I'm trying to use `clearTimeout` before my `timer();` function to reset the countdown but it seems to be breaking the timer also (which is stopping at 9).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  countdown = null;

  function timer() {
    var seconds = 10,
      el = $(".seconds");
    el.text(seconds);
    countdown = window.setTimeout(function() {
      seconds--;
      el.text(seconds);
      if (seconds > 0) {
        setTimeout(countdown, 1000);
      }
    }, 1000);
  }
  $("button").click(function() {
    clearTimeout(countdown);
    timer();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Start</button>
<button>Continue</button>
<div class="seconds"></div>
```

Comment: `setTimeout(timer, 1000)`; [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) takes a function to call, not a number.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use setTimeout(), JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19424296/how-to-use-settimeout-javascript)

Comment: give your buttons id and separate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`.

2.Take if before seconds-- so it doesnt go negative.

3.I added classes for your buttons so it doesn't confuse which one is clicked.

4.I also added a little Start/Stop user experience for you.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  countdown = null;

  function timer(input) {
    var seconds,
    el = $(".seconds");
    if (input == "Start"){
      seconds = 10;
      el.text(seconds);
      $(".start").text("Stop");
      countdown = window.setInterval(function() {
        if (seconds > 0) {
          seconds--;
          el.text(seconds);
        }
      }, 1000);
    }
    else {
      $(".start").text("Start");
      el.text(seconds);
    }
  }
  $(".start").click(function() {
    clearInterval(countdown);
    timer($(this).text());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="start">Start</button>
<button class="continue">Continue</button>
<div class="seconds"></div>
```

Comment: I really like this, it makes more logical sense than my answer, however may want to add a clearInterval call on button click in the event that user starts hitting the button multiple times or it will experience issues.

Comment: @TravisActon Thanks for your comment. I added the clearInterval and added a little user experience. changing the button text to stop and stop the countdown :)

Answer (score 0):

Along with Heretic Monkey's point, you will aslo have scoping issues. A quick refactor to pull some variables/functions outside the doc ready call would produce:

```js
var seconds;
var countdown;

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    clearTimeout(countdown);
    seconds = 10;
    timer();
  });
});

function timer() {
    $(".seconds").text(seconds);
    seconds--;
    if(seconds > 0) {
     countdown = window.setTimeout(timer,1000);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Start</button>
<button>Continue</button>
<div class="seconds"></div>
```